# Add up a column with the same key feature in csv file

Tags: python, shell, csv, programming-pearls

The columns including two key features, one column to sum up, and some other (e.g,1) column that is not important.

```
key1, key 2, pr, trivial    
abc, 43, 23, haha    
abc, 43, 456, hok    
bcd, 23, 89,kol
```

I want to add the sum column with the SAME key1 and key2, and output a csv file with 3 columns.

```
key1, key2, sumvalueofpr
```

in the above case, it is

```
key1, key2, sumvalueofpr
abc , 43, 479
bdc, 23, 89
```

(note: `479=23+456`)

To do with either Perl or Shell command is ok.

Comment: `to do with either perl or shell command is ok, as long as it works!` you didn't tag it with perl but with python instead?

Comment: @andi When editing, please try to fix everything in a post, don't just add or remove tags.

Answer (score 0):

Is there only a particular value of key1/key2 pairs or do you want to check for any possible matches?

You could do a lower performance (but easy to code) method you could try a method like this:

```
for i in range(0,number_of_rows):
   for j in range(i+1, number_of_rows):
        if (key1_from_row_i == key1_from_row_j) and (if (key1_from_row_i == key1_from_row_j)):
             increment your sum of key1_sum key2_sum
```

Answer (score 0):

if awk is accepted by you, this one-liner gives you expected output:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=", " 'NR==1{print "key1","key2","sum";next}{a[$1", "$2]+=$3}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' file
```